# Как задать отступы строки grid Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, отступы, окно

я новенький в ткинтере, прошу помочь.
Почему перед "Ваша OS: " стоит отступ? Я же выставил ему column = 0. Скрин и код ниже.

[image: Скрин окна]

```
#Вывод текста
label_OsName = Label(text = 'Ваша OS: ' + OS_platform, bg = 'pink', font = 'Times 30')
label_OsName.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

label_CurentDir = Label(text = 'Текущая директория: ' + os.getcwd(), bg = 'pink', font = 'Times 30')
label_CurentDir.grid(column = 0, row = 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

> Почему перед "Ваша OS: " стоит отступ? Я же выставил ему column = 0

Потому что `column = 0` задаёт номер столбца, в котором должен находиться `label`. А так как второй `label` больше первого, то вся таблица становится по размерам большего `label` и первый ставится (по умолчанию) по центру. Достаточно дописать для первого `label` - `sticky = NW` и он приклеится к левому верхнему краю и отступа не будет.
Вот полный код:

```
from tkinter import *
import os

root = Tk()

root["bg"] ='mediumspringgreen'

label_OsName = Label(text = 'Ваша OS: ' + OS_platform, bg = 'mediumspringgreen', font = 'Times 30')
label_OsName.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = NW)

label_CurentDir = Label(text = 'Текущая директория: ' + os.getcwd(), bg = 'mediumspringgreen', font = 'Times 30')
label_CurentDir.grid(column = 0, row = 1)

root.mainloop()
```

P.S. заголовок лучше поменять на "Как задать отступы строки grid Tkinter?" или что-то подобное. Подумайте о тех кто будет гуглить похожую проблему

Comment: Спасибо бро! Ок, поменяю